# vscode rich editing support - does not always follow require()

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code 1.2.1 and learning how the rich editing support works for javascript. (intellisense, peek, go to definition, etc)

There are two situations where vscode does successfully load the require()-ed module, but one situation that it does not provide any rich editing support. Here is an example w/ comments:

```
// vscode knows about var _ because I already did 
// $ typings install lodash
var _ = require('lodash');

// vscode knows about var fu, because the test.js is in project context.
var fu = require('./test.js');

// vscode is unaware of var tree, even though I copied the src into the 
// project context.
// $ cp -r node_modules/tnt.tree/src lib/tnt.tree
var tree = require('tnt.tree');
console.log(tree); // ok
```

The last one, tnt.tree is giving me trouble. The code above does successfully build with webpack, and run OK. But vscode says the variable tree is 'any', with no additional info.

Finally, here is my jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "diagnostics": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Summary: there are no typings for tnt.tree. So I copied the module of interest (tnt.tree) out of node_modules and into a lib/ directory, to try to make vscode aware of it in the project context. But that doesn't seem to work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, as I am sure this is a problem I will revisit over and over when trying to learn new Js modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug with the vscode team, and they reassigned it to the typescript team. So this sounds like a bug with the editor itself:

> IntelliSense based on type inference not working in node_modules?

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9323